# Navigation Hover/Active Box aren't covering the contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already tried searching all over Stack Overflow and unfortunately didn't find any possible solution thus I decided to post a question.

So I was using bootstrap 3 for the first time and I uses their navigation style, the .navbar .navbar-default and they have there own height which make the .active class on the bootstrap able to cover the whole navigation, but in my case I modify and create a new class and called it .own-navbar I added this css

```
    .own-navbar{
   height: 68px;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e2e2e2 48%, #cccccc 50%, #eaeaea 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(48%,#e2e2e2), color-stop(50%,#cccccc), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 );

}
```

and made a lot of changes and here's my navigation bar looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXx4H.png

As you guys see it, the .active class on bootstrap 3 isn't covering the whole thing. So how can I fix it?

Here's my full HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>sWIFI - Free Wifi Hotspot!</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

   <!-- SCRIPT -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
   </head>

<body>
<!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->

<div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default own-navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
         <a href="#"><img src="img/se" class="se" title="Free Wifi Hotspot" /></a>
         <h6>se</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><img src="img/seperator.png" /></li>
            <li class="active"><a class="red"href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><img src="img/seperator.png" /></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><img src="img/seperator.png" /></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><img src="img/seperator.png" /></li>
         </ul>

         <div class="search navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                     <button class="btn btn-default search-btn" type="submit">Go!</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- END OF NAVIGATION BAR -->


</body>
</html>
```

and my full CSS Code

```
/** CSS STYLING SPECIALLY MADE FOR sWIFI and CODED by urielD3 **/

/** Defaults **/
body{
   background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

/** NAVIGATION BAR & MENU **/

 .own-navbar{
   height: 68px;
   background: #ffffff;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e2e2e2 48%, #cccccc 50%, #eaeaea 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(48%,#e2e2e2), color-stop(50%,#cccccc), color-stop(100%,#eaeaea));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e2e2e2 48%,#cccccc 50%,#eaeaea 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 );

}

.own-navbar .container-fluid .navbar-header .se{
   margin: 2px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.own-navbar .container-fluid .navbar-header h6{
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #363636;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #7A7A7A;
    margin: -6px 0px 0px 55px;
    cursor: default;
}

li:hover{
/*    margin: -7px 0 0 0;
   height: 68px; */
   background: #f3f3f3;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f3f3f3 0%, #f1f1f1 53%, #e1e1e1 53%, #ffffff 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f3f3f3), color-stop(53%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(53%,#e1e1e1), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f3f3f3 0%,#f1f1f1 53%,#e1e1e1 53%,#ffffff 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f3f3f3 0%,#f1f1f1 53%,#e1e1e1 53%,#ffffff 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f3f3f3 0%,#f1f1f1 53%,#e1e1e1 53%,#ffffff 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f3f3f3 0%,#f1f1f1 53%,#e1e1e1 53%,#ffffff 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f3', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );

}
.asd{
   color: red;
}

.own-navbar .container-fluid div ul{
   margin: 7px 0px 0px 65px;
}



.own-navbar .container-fluid  div ul li a{
   color: #3B3B3B;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: Verdana;
   font-weight: bolder;
}

.own-navbar .container-fluid div ul li img{
   margin: -8px 0 0 0;
}

.own-navbar .container-fluid div .search form input{
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 305px;
   margin: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.own-navbar .container-fluid .search form .search-btn{
   border-radius: 20px;
   margin: 3px 0 0 15px;
}
```

Edit:
[Click me for the Actual Website](http://testinglang.site40.net/)

Comment: If you provide a link to the actual site it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: There you go, take a look at the website

Comment: Bootstrap doen't set a height on their navbar, it's a min-height but the actual height is set by the content inside. Your buttons are not tall enough. You will need to target the top level link and use a line-height on it or adjust the padding on the top and bottom and remove the 68 px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Christina is correct, but possibly a more direct answer to your question is you set your .own-navbar height to 68, but that isn't really doing what you want.  Your separator image height is 68px so your navbar is already at the image height.  The use of the image in the menu nav list will cause problems when the navbar collapse class is added on smaller screens.

You could use:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav li {
    height: 68px;
}
```

to try to fix the button height, but that will lead to still other issues.

You could remove the separator image and use css to create separators between buttons. The following rule is going to cause additional problems as well.

```
.own-navbar .container-fluid div ul {
  margin: 7px 0 0 65px;
}
```

That 7px top margin will give you headaches.  Adjust height with line height or padding as Christina suggested.  You can solve the left margin problem by setting min-width on div.navbar-header.

Let Bootstrap determine the final nav dimensions, responsive behavior will work better that way.